# Positioning floated list items on the bottom line when they have a smaller height

Tags: html, css

I have my navigation in a `<ul>` and the `<li>` are floated.

CSS

```
ul#nav {  
    float:right;
    margin:10;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}   

ul#nav li {
    float:left; 
    margin:10;
    width:127px;
    font-size:15px;             
}

ul#nav a{
    margin:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:transparent;
    color:rgb(46,43,52);        
}
```

Currently I get this:

[image]
Yellow = desired position | Red = actual position

How can I position the list items with a smaller height on the bottom line?

Comment: Use the red paint bucket and paint the yellow in red... or paste some CSS and HTML in question :) Don't let us guess your markup, always show the needed code so we can reproduce the issue and help you. Welcome to SO!

Comment: very funny lol, sorry.

Comment: just for fun: http://jsbin.com/dacasulaxami/1/edit

Comment: kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk aldanux made me laugh out loud

Comment: @aldanux just for super fun: http://jsbin.com/qopuw/1/edit

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - I hope he can still continue to laugh.... ;)

Comment: @aldanux no, I just don't know why after 25 min we still have no code reference!

Comment: I tought that you guys got angry, that's why I dont post the code. '^^

Comment: @user3356596 angry? we're starving to see it!! http://jsbin.com/qopuw/2/edit

Comment: @user3356596 we went a bit chatty here, but really, if you want some help you **need to show us the needed code** to reproduce the issue. If you use this website for the first time and you're not sure how to ask, you can first read the [help]! If you don't post any code your question might end up being closed.

Comment: SOrry, I was driving to home. Here it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your CSS, it makes it clear what you are trying to achieve.

- Remove the `float` and position your list items with `display: inline-block`. Inline elements will all position themselves next to each other. ([Read more about different display options here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/))
- `vertical-align: bottom` is used to keep your items positioned at the bottom of the line.
- `#nav { font-size: 0 }` fixes a gap that occurs with inline elements. You will have to set your font-size on `#nav li` or `#nav li a` ([Read more about that gap problem here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/))
- To give the list items after the first list item a different height, I have used `#nav li + li` which will target every `<li>` that has a `<li>` before it.

---

[Here is a visual example of different vertical alignments](http://jsbin.com/qoxad/2/edit):

[image: Vertical alignments example]

---

[Here is an example of the below.](http://jsbin.com/qoxad/1/edit)

HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
    font-size: 0;
}

#nav li {
    list-style: none;
  width:127px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #F00;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

#nav li + li {
    height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: To get a better reception with your next question, make sure that you include all relevant code / markup needed to reproduce the problem you are having. [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin](http://www.jsbin.com) are also very helpful when it comes to reproducing and solving the issue in your question.

Comment: I would like to thank you everybody that tries to help me even I doing everything wrong. I will improve and be a good part of the community. Thanks everybory for your time and

Sorry ! and Thanks!